# How are alkalide ions synthesized?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, ions

How are alkalide molecules synthesized, for example, I have read in a paper that the reaction $$\ce{2Na -> Na+ + Na-}$$ is exothermic with a $\Delta H = \pu{-438 kJ/mol}$.

I have also read that in the presence of a certain type of crown ether, under specific conditions, $\ce{Na+}$ crystallizes at around $\pu{-20 ^\circ C}$.

Can someone walk me through the mechanism through which sodide, or any alkalide, in general, is actually synthesized?

Comment: I think this is the crown ether in question [`[2.2.2]Cryptand`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptand)

Comment: And it's to do with [2.2.2]Cryptand being so really good at making complexes with (and stabilising) $\ce{Na+}$, that even the $\ce{Na-}$, can't reduce it

Comment: Also see: [`Alkalide (Wikipedia)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkalide)

Comment: It is not $\ce{Na+}$ crystallizing,  but it is Cript-$\ce{Na+ . Na-}$. That crystalization occured at dry ice temperature, but decomposes at $\pu{83 ^\circ C}$ (https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja00809a060)

Comment: @Mathew Mahindaratne is it possible to separate the $\ce{Na-}$ from the crystalline solid (which I understand, separated, would be pretty unstable)?

Comment: @HKhan, you can't separate charged anything from the opposite charges under anything like typical lab conditions.  You need a plasma, and even then the only stable negative charges are electrons.

Comment: Where did you get your information regarding the exothermicity of the reaction? And I think it is also important that you state exactly the states of the reactants and products involved. As far as I know, the reaction in gas phase is definitely endothermic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The reaction energetics**

Using the method of the superposition of configurations, the electron affinity of $\ce {Na}$ was theoretically determined to be $\ce {+0.54 eV}$ $\ce {^1}$, that is, around $\ce {-52.1 kJ/mol}$. The gas-phase process

$\ce {2Na (g) -> Na^+ (g) + Na^- (g)}$

has been determined to be endothermic by $\ce {4.54 eV}$ $\ce {^2}$ while the solid-state process

$\ce {2Na (s) -> Na^+ .Na^- (s)}$

has also been estimated to be endothermic by $\ce {0.8 eV}$ $\ce {^2}$.Thus, your assertion regarding the large exothermicity of the reaction is questionable. However, it is worthy to note that the $\ce { \Delta H_f}$ and $\ce {\Delta G_f}$ for $\ce {Na^+.Cry Na^-}$, where $\ce {Cry}$ = [[2.2.2] cryptand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.2.2-Cryptand), are $\ce {-10 kJ/mol}$ and $\ce {+28 kJ/mol}$ respectively $\ce {^3}$. Your large exothermic enthalpy may likely refer to the lattice energy, i.e. for the process

$\ce {M^+.Cry (g) + M^- (g) -> M^+.Cry M^- (s)}$.

For $\ce {M = Na}$, the $\ce {\Delta H}$ and $\ce {\Delta G}$ for the above process are $\ce {-323 kJ/mol}$ and $\ce {-258 kJ/mol}$ respectively $\ce {^3}$.

**Preparation of the alkalide**

$\ce {Na^-}$, $\ce {K^-}$, $\ce {Rb^-}$, and $\ce {Cs^-}$ anions are stable both in suitable solvents and in crystalline solids$\ce {^3}$. The latter can be prepared either by cooling a saturated solution $\ce {^4}$ or by rapid solvent evaporation.

The principal difficulty in preparation of crystalline salts containing alkalide ions by the method of cooling a saturated solution is the low solubility of these alkali metals in the amine and ether solutions $\ce {^3}$. Without a sufficiently large concentration of the metal dissolved in solution, precipitation of the solid upon cooling would be insignificant. This difficulty was resolved by the use of crown-ether and cryptand complexes, such as those of [18]crown-6 and [2.2.2] cryptand] $\ce {^3}$. The complexating agent complexes with $\ce {M^+}$ , shifting the equilibrium (1) far to the right, significantly increasing the concentrations of the dissolved metal ions.

(1) $\ce { 2M (s) -> M^+ (sol) + M^- (sol)}$

(2) $\ce { M^+ (sol) + Cry (sol) -> M^+.Cry}$

This technique of using complexating agents was also what Dye et al. used in their synthesis in 1973 $\ce {^4}$. As reported by Dye et al., a sufficiently concentrated solution of sodium metal (in excess) dissolved in ethylamine with [2.2.2] cryptand was first prepared. The solution is then cooled to dry ice temperatures, giving a gold-coloured crystalline solid precipitate. Through thorough analysis, this precipitate was then determined to be $\ce {Na^+.Cry Na^- (s)}$ with $\ce {Cry}$ being the [2.2.2] cryptand.

**References**

1. Weiss, A. W. Theoretical Electron Affinities for Some of the Alkali and
   Alkaline-Earth Elements. *Phys. Rev.*, **1968**, *166* (1), 70-74
2. Tehan, F. J.; Barnett, B. L.; Dye, J. L. Alkali anions. Preparation and Crystal Structure of a Compound which contains the Cryptated Sodium Cation and the Sodium Anion. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1974**, *96* (23), 7203–7208
3. Dye, J. L. Compounds of Alkali Metal Anions. *Angew. Chem.*, **1979**, *18* (8), 587-598
4. Dye, J. L.; Ceraso, J. M.; Lok, M. T.; Barnett, B. L.; Tehan, F. J. A Crystalline Salt of the Sodium Anion (Na-). *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1974**, *96* (2), 608-609