# How many multivalent elements are there?

Tags: transition-metals, ionic-compounds

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWTXAhkvRxc&t=51s) there are 20 multivalent elements, and from the periodic table, I see 20, but according to multiple websites, including [this](http://bookbuilder.cast.org/view_print.php?book=68760), it says there are only 5. What am I not understanding? Are there 20 or 5? I want to know so I can memorize them. Also, are there any that aren't transition metals that are exceptions, i.e. non-metal multivalent? If so, may you please list them in your response?

Again talking about *multivalent elements* because I am learning ionic compounds, and these are part of it. Also, please keep high-level vocabulary to a minimum, I know some science vocabulary but i am only in grade 10.

Edit: I would like to add that i am referring to how many metals have roman numbers, i.e like Fe which has 2+ and 3+ charge both. are there more than 5 of these or are there 20?

To anyone with the same question: [this article](https://www.americanchemistry.com/chemistry-in-america/news-trends/blog-post/2018/discover-the-world-of-transition-metals#:%7E:text=There%20are%20total%20of%2038,%2C%20Manganese%2C%20Zinc%20and%20Mercury) (thanks to Achem) and [the article listed here](https://www.romannumerals.org/blog/roman-numerals-in-chemistry-13) article are very useful.

Comment: You should not memorize all the periodic element's oxidation states randomly. Nobody will expect you to know all the elements. Learn the valency common elements which are mentioned in your grade-10 books. It is quite easy to see a pattern. Group I elements will exist as (+), group II elements (2+), etc. The transition elements show multiple valencies.

Comment: Im aware of that just ask extra pratice. could you please answer my question though? I know the (+) and (-) tendencies aswell

Comment: Both videos/websites are wrong. There are more than 20 elements which have multiple valency. All transition metals will show multivalency. All lanthanide and actinide elements show multivalency. Count how many transition elements are there in the periodic table. It is certainly more than 20.

Comment: no!!! That's not what i meant. I meant how many transition metals are there, that have more than one roman numeral sign / charge like Fe which has 2+ and 3+ i.e Iron(11) or Iron(1). How many metals have that, could you please list them so i can write them down as notes. I know that many transition metals have more than one atom, im just wondering for the roman numeral in specific

Comment: This is **exactly** what I am trying to tell you, there are about 38 transition elements and they will show multivalency. So both websites are **wrong**. There are more than 20 multivalent elements. Fe(III) and $\ce{Fe^{3}}$ is the same thing.

Comment: So there are 38 elements that have roman numerals or more than one charge like Fe(III) and Fe3 Please confirm, that is what your saying

Comment: Read this link: https://www.americanchemistry.com/chemistry-in-america/news-trends/blog-post/2018/discover-the-world-of-transition-metals#:~:text=There%20are%20total%20of%2038,%2C%20Manganese%2C%20Zinc%20and%20Mercury.

Comment: Thanks for helping me so much!!! I didnt know that the 38 transition elements all had roman numeral charges like that. Guess i aint memerozing or writing them down lol

Comment: You are not supposed to memorize those 38 elements.

Comment: Elements with a single valency are the minority.

Comment: Valency is not always a clear-cut concept in chemistry. Also, beyond all the d and f elements (which Achem mentioned), many p elements and even H is multivalent (H- is clearly different than H+).

Comment: I'm surprised those fraudulent papers saying there are only 20 or 5 multivalent elements got published—illiteracy to the highest level.

Comment: The elements that aren't multivalent in my understanding are alkali metals, alkaline earth metals, fluorine, and noble gases. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @BruhMoments All the alkali metals except Li have at least M+ and M- to my knowledge (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkalide , https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/109846/unusual-oxidation-states-of-alkali-metals/109854#109854). Also to my knowledge the alkaline earths except Be form monovalent compounds involving M-M bonds (https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2011/dt/c0dt01831g#!divAbstract). Ar, Kr, Xe and Rn all form well defined compounds (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas_compound), Xe and Rn in multiple oxidation states.

Comment: Almost all of them, maybe?

Comment: haha i was so dumb back thrn! Thanks to everyone who assisted me